# "rails" como sinônimo da tag "ruby-on-rails"

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tags, tags-sinônimas

Há algum tempo atrás, eu percebi que quase todas as perguntas sobre Ruby on Rails utilizava [ruby-on-rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), e que apenas algumas poucas perguntas utilizavam [rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails).

Então eu editei as perguntas que tinha [rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails) trocando a *tag* para que ela fosse deletada, pois não tinha ainda o direito de sugerir um sinônimo de *tag*.

Acontece que, inevitavelmente, alguns usuários voltaram a utilizar [rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails), então agora eu lancei a sugestão de sinônimo.

Será que vocês podem entrar [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails/synonyms) e dar um *upvote* lá na sugestão? Ou talvez um dos moderadores possa aprová-la de uma vez, já que não vejo qualquer motivo para não fazê-lo.

Comment: Pegando carona: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o/synonyms

Comment: @bigown Tentei votar mas não tenho a pontuação necessária nessa *tag*. =)

Comment: Pronto, sinônimo criado! :) O seu também, @bigown!